# How to manage mutiple Instances of Settings in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, architecture, software-design

I have drawing application, in which user can work on multiple drawings at same time.
Lets say a user has opened 4 drawings on -> top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right respectively.

Previously, I had a static settings file and all the 4 drawings were using the same settings. Now I need to implement different settings file for all the 4 drawings. So user can have different tolerances in different drawings. The settings are read from Json.

**If I create a settings() object then I will have to pass it to every variable which needs the value from settings.**

Previously, I could just do

```
var dim = Settings.Tolerance;
```

This is making the program really ugly and I am forced to pass settings in every function from top to bottom and also extension methods.

**Is there any thing I can do to avoid this?**

I am implementing this in C# , .net core.

Comment: If you have a static property on a class you can just as easily have four instances of the same class associated with different views.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions could be to stick with the static class, and have the class to hold multiple instances of your `settings` object.

In the following example class `SettingsCollection` is used to hold multiple instances of your `Settings` object, places inside `System.Collections.Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` settings instances are identified by single `Int32` but you could also use `Strings` or what ever suits your application.

De/serializing the `System.Collections.Dictionary<int,Settings>` to Json and should work just fine, and you will end up with Json that looks something like this:

```json
{
    "1": {
        "Tolerance": 10,
        "SomeOtherValue": 1.15,
        "SomeStringValue": "hello from settings instance 1"
    },
    "2": {
        "Tolerance": 100,
        "SomeOtherValue": 1.20,
        "SomeStringValue": "hello from settings instance 2"
    },
    "3": {
        "Tolerance": 20,
        "SomeOtherValue": 2.30,
        "SomeStringValue": "hello from settings instance 3"
    },
    "4": {
        "Tolerance": 200,
        "SomeOtherValue": 3.1,
        "SomeStringValue": "hello from settings instance 4"
    }
}
```

Settings are loaded from the file when the application tries to access them for the first time, but this could also be done manually when application is started.

```
    public class Settings
    {
        /*Your settings object*/
    }

    // using System.Collections.Generic;
    // Class that hold dictionary of your 'Settings' instances.
    // Here settings instances are identified by the `Int32` numeric identifier, but you can of course use anything that suits your needs.
    public class SettingsCollection
    {
        public Dictionary<int, Settings> Settings;
    }

    // Static class that holds the instance of `SettingsCollection`.
    // In this example the `_Instance` is initialized when the it is accessed for the first time, you could also initialize the `_Instance` by your self for example when application is started.
    public static class SettingsContainer
    {
        private SettingsCollection? _Instance = null;

        public SettingsCollection Instance {
            get {
                if (_Instance == null) {
                    _Instance = LoadFromFile();
                }

                return _Instance;
            }
        }

        private SettingsCollection LoadFromFile()
        {
            string jsonString = "";/* load json from the file */
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SettingsCollection>(jsonString);
        }

        public void Save() => SaveToFile(Instance);

        private void SaveToFile(SettingsCollection settings)
        {
            string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(s);
            /* Write json to file */
        }
    }
```

Usage example:

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Settings drawing1Settings = SettingsContainer.Instance.Settings[1];

            // or

            if (!settingsCollection.Settings.TryGetValue(1, out Settings drawing1Settings)) {
                // settings instance not found with key `1`
            } else {
                // settings instance found
            }
        }
    }
```